# how to create a .hpub for baker framework with css and jquery files

Tags: ios

I am very new to the baker framework, 
however i knew that i have to create the hpub file
do we have to also zip our images, css and jquery files or we just have to zip the html files?

also, how to create book:// instead of http://

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to zip up all the files into your hpub file. However note that you have to zip them without the parent directory jut the files that make up your content, images, css, etc

So, if your files for your hpub were in a directory called "MyGreatNewBook", from the command line you would make an hpub file like this:

```
 cd MyGreatNewBook
 zip -r ~/MyGreatNewBook.hpub .
```

this would zip up all your files and place the hpub file in your home directory.